# Restricting `using` directives to the current file

Tags: c++, using-directives

Sorry for this silly question, but is there any way to restrict `using` directives to the current file so that they don't propagate to the files that `#include` this file?

Comment: You can restrict using directives to a non-file scope, though, such as a namespace or a function.

Comment: It is much better not to apply the `using` directive in headers.

Comment: @David: I hate typing something like `std::map<std::string, std::tr1::tuple<int, std::string> >` when I can type `map<string, tuple<int, string> >`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps wrapping the code to be included inside its own namespace could achieve the behavior
you want, since name spaces have scope affect.

```
// FILENAME is the file to be included
namespace FILENAME_NS {
   using namespace std;
   namespace INNER_NS {
      [wrapped code]
   }
}
using namespace FILENAME_NS::INNER_NS;
```

and in some other file

```
#include <FILENAME>
// std namespace is not visible, only INNER_NS definitions and declarations
...
```

Comment: Hey, cool trick! I think I'll go for this one; Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 15):

No, there isn't, which is why you should not use using directives in header files, or any other file that you #include.

Comment: To extend this a little bit - the preprocessor (which handles `#include` and other `#`-commands) runs before the compiler ever sees the code. The `using` directive and any other standard keywords are processed by the compiler. Thus, as far as the compiler is concerned, the header files aren't actually separate files - they're code that happens to be in every file in which they are `#include`'d, and thus so are any `using` directives you might put in them.

Comment: Aah... sad. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @Rahul It's not that bad - you can (and should) of course use `using` directives in your .cpp files.

Answer (score 4):

Technically you should be able to import them to some internal namespace, and then make the things declared in that visible in the namespace meant for the user.

```
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP

#include <string>

namespace my_detail
{
    using std::string;
    inline string concatenate(const string& a, const string& b) { return a + b; }   
}

namespace my_namespace
{
    using my_detail::concatenate;
}

#endif
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.hpp"

using namespace my_namespace;

int main() 
{
    std::  //required
    string a("Hello "), b("world!");
    std::cout << concatenate(a, b) << '\n';
}
```

Not sure if it is worth the trouble and how well it plays with "argument-dependent lookup".

Comment: Too much of trouble indeed. But still a nice work around. So, +1. :)